# list styles css, getting a) in list instead of a

Tags: html, css

Is there a why to create ordered list to display a) instead of a. when using css with the ul/li tag

At the moment I have this style `ol.lower-alpha {list-style-type:lower-alpha}` which produces a. and not a)

eg.

I need it to look like this

```
 a) item 1
 b) item 2
```

Comment: no css list-style-type will give you that.. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: @stian.net - Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Not with css. You will have to : a) item 1<br/>b) item 2<br/> and so on...

Comment: @stian.net - Will need to convince the client to use a. instead of a) since using a) with <br /> will cause the second line to be under the a) eg.
a) test line
continues

Comment: thats true!.. It's just not possible with css. You will have to use tables to achive that.. Convince the client sounds like a better idea :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using counters (which have good, but still limited support, so take care). Example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8KKb/)):

```
ol {
   list-style-type: none;
   counter-reset: list;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
    counter-increment: list;
}
```

Comment: This works, but a bit worried to use this, since the display also needs to be exported to pdf, and tcpdf might just not support it yet